# Recursive function returns empty arrays

Tags: javascript, recursion

This code is meant to get all sub-elements and its children into one array. However it returns bunch of empty arrays.

```
function get_independent_elements_from(element) {

    var independent_elements = [];

    if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        var children = element.children;

        for (let child of children) {
            independent_elements = independent_elements.concat(get_independent_elements_from(child));
        }
    } else {
        independent_elements.push(element);
    }

    return independent_elements;
}
```

Comment: please add some data to try it. [mcve]

Comment: Your `this.element` should be a local variable. As it is, every recursive call is using the same variable (a global one).

Comment: Nah. It's not it.

Comment: @MateuszSkorupiński then please re-test your now edited code and check its behaviour, because it's _not_ returning empty arrays.

Comment: NB: your code only returns leaf nodes.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: I think maybe that you call `get_independent_elements_from(child)` in the same function will cause an infinite loop

Comment: @Altiniak indeed.

Comment: and have you tried your edited version?  As far as I can see it actually works.

Comment: @Altiniak The code which is above works for you?

Comment: @MateuszSkorupiński yes, it does.

Comment: @Altiniak Could you give me your code then? Just to compare.

Comment: I don't have "my" code, other than my completely alternate version in my answer.   I just copy and pasted your code, and verified that it returns the same answer as my version using `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your new code does appear to work, you could also get the browser to do the heavy lifting for you without recursion:

```
function getLeafNodes(el) {
    let nl = el.querySelectorAll('*');
    return [].filter.call(nl, x => !x.firstChild);
}
```

Here's a potentially more efficient recursive version which just closes over a single array and handles the recursion internally:

```
function getLeadNodes(el) {
    let r = [];
    (function loop(x) {
        if (x.children.length) {
            [].forEach.call(x.children, loop);
        } else {
            r.push(x);
        }
    })(el);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element like this:

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

element.hasChildNodes() will return ture,but element.children return a empty HTMLCollection.

You can change the if condition to take a try.

```
if (element.children.length) { xxx }
```

thank you to give advice or comments to me.